# What's the difference between attribute.present? and attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm learning Rails and I'm working on an extremely basic RSVP app where if the user has entered both a name and an e-mail address, a method called `rsvp?` in my User model returns `true`.

If my method is defined as:

```
def rsvp?
  name.present? && email.present?
end
```

I get the same results as if it was:

```
def rsvp?
  name? && email?
end
```

So is saying `name.present?` the same as `name?`  I was told that `name.present?` would not only check for `nil` values, but also for empty string values.  But it appears that `name?` accomplishes the same thing (tested all four permutations of name & e-mail, name but no e-mail, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`present?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L19) returns the opposite of [`blank?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L14). They're Rails extensions of Ruby's core [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html). `.present?` will return `false` if the value being testing is `nil`, `""`, `{}`, `false`, `[]`, etc... based on the type *(`Array`, `Hash`, `String`, etc...)* extending `Object`.

Methods like `name?` which are based on the attributes of your model like `:name` are actually passed through the [`method_missing`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L51) method in `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods` which is then processed by `ActiveModel::AttributeMethods`and eventually processed by **[this class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/query.rb)**.

So, **yes** they are mostly the same *(for certain column types `blank?` is actually called; the same `blank?` in `present?` above)*, but they're not **identical**, as the `?` suffix methods do some additional checking based on the column type.